# Direct traffic from google domain to elastic beanstalk without changing name server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk app which I have successfully connected to my google domain name by changing my name server. The only problem is that all my google DNS records/email settings are now disabled since I am using amazon's name servers. I could transfer my domain to route 53 however I must remain using GSuite for work related reasons.

How can I direct traffic from my google domain to elastic beanstalk without changing the name server? I am fairly inexperience with DNS so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only problem is that all my google DNS records/email settings are
> now disabled since I am using amazon's name servers.

All you needed to do was create another CNAME record in your DNS server that pointed to the Elastic Beanstalk instance (or load balancer). You didn't need to change name servers.